# accessing values globally

Tags: php

I have 2 files namely:

1. *uploading.php*
2. *emaillinks.php*

both include a file *inc.php* which has all the include files and initiate database connection.

a variable is declared in file *uploading.php*, i wanted to know how can i access it in *emaillinks.php*, i cant include *uploading.php* in *emaillinks.php*.

I want to avoid cookies because data is big and always different.

what is the best option to make it accessible by emaillinks.php?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what it is, you could put it into the database or into the [session](http://php.net/session_start) (`$_SESSION`)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't include you'll need to go with session variables or cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question the words "registry pattern" suddenly popped into my head.  This might be a bit of overkill for your needs, but it might be worth looking into.

You'd probably have to do a lot of refactoring to make this solution available.  So you'd probably be best using the session, database or some text file to store your variable.

Here is a [good article](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/design-patterns---singleton-and-singleton-registry) on using a registry, though (if you're interested).